# Using puppeteer to perform multiple actions at the same time with data obtained from the user

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

well, I'm trying to build an app that will have a client-side interface where the user will be able to put information (login ID and pass, for example).

What I want to achieve is that every time a new user registers and sets information on the client-side interface, that info will be sent to the server where a puppeteer script will use it in order to do actions in another webpage.

So, let's say that this info is the user's Twitter ID and password. I want puppeteer to use that info to login into user's Twitter account and retrieve some specific data.

My questions are the following:

-Is this possible to be done with puppeteer?

-How can I send information from client side to server side in a way that puppeteer can obtain it and launch a new browser task?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send information from client to server, you can (for example) use jQuery `ajax` (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or `axios` (https://github.com/axios/axios) to send a `post` request to the server with username and password in body.

Below is an example on how to login then go to user's settings page and scrap user's selected language from there. It should work 99% of time, although I've noticed that Twitter sometimes serves a different loading page with varying class selectors so you would have to handle it appropriately if you want it to work 100% of time.

In this scenario, you send a `post` request to `/puppeteer` endpoint. `req.body` is your `ajax` request's data/body, which should be in the following format: `{ username: 'username', password: 'password' }`. If you set `headless` parameter to `true`, Puppeteer will open a Chromium browser window in which you can see the whole process.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.set('trust proxy')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const http = require('http')

app.post('/puppeteer', async (req, res) => {
    const LOGIN_URL = `https://twitter.com/login`
    const ACCOUNT_URL = `https://twitter.com/settings/account`
    const CREDENTIALS = req.body

    // Setting up Puppeteer
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 926 })

    // Go to login page
    await page.goto(LOGIN_URL)

    // Let's wait until submit button is available, without this you won't be able to login
    await page.waitForSelector('.submit')

    // Let's fill in the form and submit it
    await page.$eval('.js-username-field', (el, payload) => el.value = payload, CREDENTIALS.username)
    await page.$eval('.js-password-field', (el, payload) => el.value = payload, CREDENTIALS.password)
    await page.click('button.submit')

    // Wait for navigation in case there's some redirect
    await page.waitForNavigation()

    // We are logged in, now navigate to the page you want to get data from, i.e. account settings
    await page.goto(ACCOUNT_URL)

    // Wait for #user_lang select list
    await page.waitForSelector('#user_lang')

    // Find out what's user's selected language (there might be a better way to do this, I rarely need to do DOM manipulations)
    const userLanguage = await page.$eval('#user_lang', languages => [].map.call(languages, lang => { return { lang: lang.textContent, selected: lang.selected } }).find(el => el.selected).lang)

    // This scenario assumes we succeed, so I return a successful response, but you might want to return different error codes based on results
    return res.status(200).json(userLanguage)
})

const server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(8000)
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for your answer! helped a lot :)

Comment: What's the meaning of the argument 'payload' at the form filling section?

Comment: You can't pass CREDENTIALS directly into your page eval part, so it has to be accessed by passing it as a payload. The name can be different though.

Comment: May you please further explain the payload topic to me? I'm not familiar with it.